# How to serialise only name of variant and ignore value for enum field in struct (serde)

Tags: serialization, struct, rust, enums, serde

Given the definitions:

```rs
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum Bar {
  A(i64),
  B(u64),
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
  bar: Bar,
}
```

the JSON serialisation for

```rs
Foo {
  bar: Bar::A(123),
}
```

would be:

```json
{
  "bar": "A"
}
```

It would be ideal to add an attribute to the field in the struct instead of inside the enum definition (the enum will be reused in a struct field where the value needs to be serialised too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute [`#[serde(skip)]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#skip) can be used on tuple variant fields:

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize}; // 1.0.126
use serde_json; // 1.0.64

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum Bar {
    A(#[serde(skip)] i64),
    B(#[serde(skip)] u64),
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    bar: Bar,
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo { bar: Bar::A(123) };
    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&foo).unwrap());
}
```

```
{"bar":"A"}
```

If modifying `Bar` isn't an option, you'll have to do it a bit more manually via [`#[serde(with = ...)]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#with) or [`#[serde(serialize_with = ...)]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#serialize_with):

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize, ser::Serializer}; // 1.0.126
use serde_json; // 1.0.64

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum Bar {
    A(i64),
    B(u64),
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    #[serde(serialize_with = "bar_name_only")]
    bar: Bar,
}

fn bar_name_only<S>(bar: &Bar, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
where
    S: Serializer,
{
    let name = match bar {
        Bar::A(_) => "A",
        Bar::B(_) => "B",
    };

    serializer.serialize_str(name)
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo { bar: Bar::A(123) };
    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&foo).unwrap());
}
```

```
{"bar":"A"}
```

Comment: would you say it's worth just making another enum for this or doing it the manual way?

Comment: @JawadAhmed Up to you. Another enum could be worth it if you use it by name-only in other places, but an isolated case like this I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: i will stick to the latter method, will make things a little less complex overall, thank you :)